# How to merge the master/any branch into the main branch which is the default branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

**I have pushed my code to the branch name master, but the default branch is main**
**So, the main problem is, my code files is not visible on the main branch, where people navigate**
*Can anyone help me to merge the master name branch to the main branch which is the defualt brach, so when people visit my project, the code will be seen on that branch.*[image]

The main branch is looking like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the name of the project? It will be easier if I can look at the tree

Comment: What's blocking you? Did you try to merge?

Comment: or just send a picture of it: `git fetch; gitk --all` and then make a screenshot (or use a different repo browser tool if you have one you prefer)

Comment: Just ... merge master into main?

Comment: Yes, my question is to merge master branch(holding all the application code) into the main branch. @CodeCaster

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the main branch in your local. And then trigger the command `"git merge master"`. Then push the main branch.

Answer (score 0):

you can push your master branch then use pull request to the main branch in github or gitlab and it will merge with your main branch, but make sure that you don't have any conflicts.

Comment: Can, give me a favor by sending these step by step commands

Comment: sure, which source control do you use?github,gitlab...

Comment: I am using the Github and for command line gitbash

Comment: first push your branch then go to your repository in your github, after that you can see the pull request tab up to the left, then you can see the new pull request button click on that and set the base:main and compare:master  https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request

Comment: let me know if that is working??

Comment: Yes, can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your message and include all required informations such as docs and commands

Comment: I put a document link above